# adding @XmlAttribute to a simple type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to add an attribute using javax.xml.bind.annotation to a simple type (String in this case)

so i want this

```
<myObj><stuff foo="bar">data</stuff></myObj>
```

if stuff is a string inside of 'myObj' , is this possible?

I know that this is most likely easy i was just having trouble finding an example that added an attribute to a non-complex type.

thanks so much!

Comment: Similar to this question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666467/how-can-i-add-xml-attributes-to-jaxb-annotaded-class-xmlelementwrapper

Comment: The following may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Comment: What value has 'stuff'? "data"? or "bar"? What is 'foo' here?

Comment: sorry that it was a bit vague, but stuff i want to be a string in my bean, but the foo i would like to be an attribute of that string, but i would like to do it without creating an additional object of type stuff that would contain just a string and one attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate leaving things hanging... Basically what i was trying to do was to add an attribute to a String who was residing in the class , but what i had to do was to wrap that string into a pojo who had an xmlvlaue as well as other members for the attributes.

thanks