# TomEE Resteasy JAX-B -> Can not get Nested Object

Tags: rest, jaxb, nested, resteasy

I'm working on a RestWebService using Resteasy. The basic implementation works fine. Know I tried to return a Complexer- Object through rest...
Actually its pretty easy..I thought. I'm getting a problem because of my nested object (Address)...

What I try is this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1199647317278849602L;
    private String uri;
    private String vName;
    private String nName;
    private Address address;

        .....

        @XmlElementWrapper(name="Former-User-Ids")
    @XmlElement(name="Adress")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
....
```

Address looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "address")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address {
    private String uri;
    private String street;
    private String city;

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
```

....
The Restservice looks like this. It worked perfect without the address object..

```
    @Path("/getPersonXML/{personNumber}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Patient getPatientXML(@PathParam("personNumber") String personNumber) throws ParseException {

        Address a1 = new Address("de.person/address/" + "432432","Teststret12","TestCity", "32433", "TestCountry", "081511833");
        Patient p1 = new Person();
        p1.setAddress(a1);
        p1.setUri("de.spironto/person/"+ "432432");
        p1.setnName("Power");
        p1.setvName("Max");
        return p1;
    }
```

At the moment I'm always getting a

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException:

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After building a small marshaller test. I got the failure that there are several properties with the same name. So I tried to  delete all @XML_Eleemets annotations in the Address class. 
That worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**PROBLEM**

The `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation must be used with a collection property.  This means you can have:

```
@XmlElementWrapper
public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
    return phoneNumbers;
}
```

But not

```
@XmlElementWrapper
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}
```

**SOLUTION #1 - Using Any JAXB Proivder**

You could use an `XmlAdapter` to accomplish this (see linked answer below):

- [Access attribute of internal element in the most simple way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391043/access-attribute-of-internal-element-in-the-most-simple-way/12393273#12393273)

**SOLUTION #2 - Using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**

You could leverage the `@XmlPath` extension to map this use case:

```
@XmlPath("Former-User-Ids/Address")
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html