# How to unmarshall xml string to object using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

am using jaxb for converting xml response to java object, i have tried but am getting null for nested class object.

XML String

```
<person>
    <name>name</name>
    <age>12</age>
    <address>
        <info>
            <contactadress>
                <city>
                </city>
                <phone>
                </phone>
            </contactadress>
        </info>
    </address>
</person>
```

mapping java class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class person
{
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "age")
    int age:

    @XmlElement(name = "address/info/contactadress")
    person.Address address;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "contactadress")
    public static class Address{

        @XmlElement(name = "city")
        String city;

        @XmlElement(name = " phone")
        String phone;
    }
}
```

JaxB code:

```
public Person parseXml(String xmlResponse, Person pserson)
{

 StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlResponse);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(pserson.class);
            XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(stringReader);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            return unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
}
```

after converstion am getting address object is null.

Comment: where is the jaxb code?

Comment: jaxb code perfectly fine , this mapping only incrorrect

Comment: please post th jaxb code too

Comment: i have updated jaxb code

Comment: The element type "contactadress" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</contactadress>"

Comment: this xml is test data, i have same structured xml data , matching end tag is not my solustion @LMK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57847/discussion-between-lmk-and-ydder).

Answer (score 0):

your Person class should look like this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"name",
"age",
"address"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person {

@XmlElement(required = true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "NCName")
protected String name;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected BigInteger age;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected Address address;

/**
 * Gets the value of the name property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the name property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setName(String value) {
    this.name = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the age property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link BigInteger }
 *     
 */
public BigInteger getAge() {
    return age;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the age property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link BigInteger }
 *     
 */
public void setAge(BigInteger value) {
    this.age = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the address property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link Address }
 *     
 */
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the address property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link Address }
 *     
 */
public void setAddress(Address value) {
    this.address = value;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@XmlElement` annotation does not allow you to specify a path as the element name as you have done in your question.  Instead you would need classes for each level of nesting.  These classes could be leveraged via an `XmlAdapter` if you wanted (see:  [Access attribute of internal element in the most simple way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391043/access-attribute-of-internal-element-in-the-most-simple-way/12393273#12393273)).

```
@XmlElement(name = "address/info/contactadress")
person.Address address;
```

In [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) we do offer an `@XmlPath` extension that lets you do this:

```
@XmlPath("address/info/contactadress")
person.Address address;
```

I have written more about this use case on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html