# JAXB variable attribute name, is it possible?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have to production something like this:

```
<Doc p1="something">
    <Ext code="one"/>
    <Ext name="two"/>
</Doc>
```

I know how to do the  part with my Doc class, the "code" and "name" are just properties of the Doc, so I was going to create a wrapper class Ext to produce that element, but I'm not sure how to use "code" as the attribute in one case and "name" as the attribute in another case.  I could always create two different wrapper classes I suppose, but I was wondering if there was an easier way, such as some way to set what the @XmlAttribute(name=) will be with a variable somehow.

Comment: Try looking at this 

[click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666467/how-can-i-add-xml-attributes-to-jaxb-annotated-class-xmlelementwrapper

Comment: completely different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do - as LINEMAN78 said, variable attribute names do not a valid XSD make.  If you know what your list of candidate attributes consists of (e.g. your Exts can have Code, Name, Foo, Bar, and Baz), you can just use `@XmlAttribute`s to define them; by default an `XmlAttribute` is not required and, if the Java object value is `null`, will not show up in the marshalled output.

Comment: Only downside is that it is still valid to specify none or all of the attributes so there is no inherit validation.

Answer (score 0):

Variable attribute names are not valid for an xml schema definition, but you can do a choice for an element, so it would be:

```
<Doc p1="something">
    <Code>one</Code>
    <Name>two</Name>
</Doc>
```

To do this you would use a JaxbElement and it wouldn't require a wrapper class. The xsd would look like this:

```
<complexType name="Doc">
    <sequence>
        <choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <element name="Code" type="string" />
            <element name="Name" type="string" />
        </choice>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="p1" type="string" />
</complexType>
```

Which would result in the following code:

```
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "Code", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "Name", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
})
protected List<JAXBElement<String>> codeOrName;
```

Where JaxbElement is used like this:

```
new JAXBElement<String>(new QName( "", "Name" ), String.class, Doc.class, value);
```