# XML Element with attribute by using Java annotations

Tags: java, xml, annotations

I can create an XML element in Java by using the annotation [javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html)

```
@XmlElement(name="foo")
```

that produces the following XML element

```
<foo/>
```

Now, I want to create the following tag:

```
<foo attr="attrval"/>
```

How can I do that by using annotations?

Comment: Have you tried [@XmlAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html) annotation?

Comment: Yes, it creates an attribute for the `@XmlRootNode`. It doesn't create a new empty element with an attribute. I know, I can create a new class FOO with the attribute `@XmlAttribute` and then create an object FOO annotated with the `@XmlElement`, but it looks a lot verbose to me.

Comment: You can use this:[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666467/how-can-i-add-xml-attributes-to-jaxb-annotated-class-xmlelementwrapper

Comment: @WenodPathirana It is exactly what I said! I have to create a class that embeds the annotation for the attribute. Nothing less verbose?