# issue on read XML child, http POST, Spring MVC

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, http-post

I already have the implementation to post the xml data to my controller but I am having some issues with the data I am trying to read due the XML format I given work with.

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE} )
    public ResponseEntity<?>  SlaDetails(@RequestBody AgentSla[] task_sla) {
        MessageDto messageDto = new MessageDto();
        for (AgentSla next: task_sla){
            System.out.println(next.getStage());
        }
        messageDto.setMsg("ok");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(messageDto);
    }
```

My Entity:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="task_sla")
    public class AgentSla {

    private Long id;
    private String stage;
    private String timezone;

    //getters and setters
```

XML doc sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<task_sla>
<stage>boo</stage>
<timezone display_value="IN">12345</timezone>
</task_sla>

<task_sla>
<stage>foo</stage>
<timezone display_value="SR">12345</timezone>
</task_sla>
</xml>
```

**The Issue:** I can read any value of the XML "subchilds" i.e "`<stage>boo</stage>`" or <`/timezone>` the problem I have is on the "`<timezone display_value="IN">12345</timezone>`". On this child it reads only the value "12345" but I also need the "**display_value="SR"** " value. 
Is it possible to read that value or...should I just give up.

Answer (score 0):

you should make a new class for `timezone` field and use `@XmlAttribute`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "timezone")
public class Timezone {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "display_value")
    private String displayValue;

    @XmlValue
    private String timezoneValue;

    // write your getters and setters
}
```

Then use `Timezone` class in your

```
@XmlRootElement(name="task_sla")
public class AgentSla {
    private Long id;
    private String stage;
    private Timezone timezone;
    // getters and setters
}
```

see here:

[How can I add xml attributes to jaxb annotated class XmlElementWrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666467/how-can-i-add-xml-attributes-to-jaxb-annotated-class-xmlelementwrapper)

[XML element with attribute and content using JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514752/xml-element-with-attribute-and-content-using-jaxb)

Comment: - right but how would I bind in my controller against my AgentSla  class ?

Comment: replace `String timezone` by `Timezone timezone`